# Parsing string into key value pairs

Tags: json, regex, parsing

```
{key1:value, key2:value1,value2, key3:data, key4:value, time: 13:10:05, Location, key5:value1,value2, key6:value}
```

I want to parse data into key and value pairs.
The keys can have any name and so is value. Value can have commas and colons as well so you don't have any parameter to separate it.

see the above example string. Key value pairs are also no enclosed in ""

I'm pretty good with coding but this problem is becoming a challenge for me!

Comment: You can try to use JSON parser and it will be comparatively easy.

Comment: Surely the language you're using has some sort of JSON parser already written.  Use that instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var input = "{key1:value, key2:value1,value2, key3:data, key4:value, time: 13:10:05, Location, key5:value1,value2, key6:value}";

var regexp = /(key\d+):(.+?)(?=((, key)|}))/ig;

var result;
while (result = regexp.exec(input)) {
    console.log(`key: "${result[1]}", value "${result[2]}"`)
}
```

But this will only work if you have naming for keys like `key1, key2, key100` etc.